# maven can't resolve dependency's dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a library called `sample-lib` which has a dependency to `com.google.guava`, here is part of the pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.my</groupId>
<artifactId>sample-lib</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>16.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I finished this library I deployed it to our internal maven repo server( we use JFrog Artifactory).

Then in one of our project we use this `sample-lib`, we have reference it in project's pom.xml as :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Because we think `sample-lib` already has a dependency to google guava, we don't add the latter to the project's pom file. The problem is when we run project we got 'class not found for com.google.guava.xxxx class'. If we add guava dependency to project pom, everything is ok. Why the guava dependency can't be resolved since we the `sample-lib` already use it?

We found some open source project are not like this, when we use one library we will got all its dependencies auto imported.

How this happen? Is there some issue in our `sample-lib`'s pom file or some thing wrong with our internal maven repo server?

Comment: There could be a versioning issue whereby the version of Guava which `sample-lib` pulls in is not compatible with other areas of code which expect either a newer or older version of Guava.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, we will check it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's not the reason, we add one open source library to the `sample-lib`, this library is absolutely not used in project code, still get its class not found error.

Comment: Do a `mvn help:effective-pom` and check if your `guava` dependency is declared in the `<dependencyManagement>` section as having `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and search guava and it's version in output

Comment: @Daniel  @michaldo When I do `mvn help:effective-pom`, `guava` is not in dependency list; but when I do `mvn dependency:tree`, `guava` appears in the `sample-lib`'s dependency as compile